# POST data to Firebase using Python

Tags: python, firebase

I am using python-firebase and can't seem to get data to POST properly. Whatever I send is POSTED to firebase but the entities are not viewable in the dashboard as JSON. Here is my code:

```
json = '{ url: "' + url + '" address: "' + address + '" name: "' + name + '"}'
result = firebase.post("/businesses", json )
```

In the Dashboard for a POSTED entity I see:

[image]

Any idea on how I can get the entities to POST properly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your JSON keys need to be strings in quotes. There are also no commas in your JSON string. Neatest way is to use the `json` library:

```
import json

# your variables are already assigned before this
data = {'url': url, 'address': address, 'name': name}
sent = json.dumps(data)
result = firebase.post("/businesses", sent)
```

Comment: How do you get the document id of the above added document?

Answer (score 5):

Your JSON is not valid (no commas between dict entries) but you can post a normal dict instead of a JSON string anyway:

```
data = {'url': url, 
        'address': address,
        'name': name}
result = firebase.post("/businesses", data)
```